# Can't install pydev in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'd like install pydev in eclipse by following method, all of them fails:

1. using update site, errors happens in the installation, looks like a firewall issue.
2. download the pydev zip file, and extract to the eclipse folder, not working ( could not find it in preference after restart eclipse)
3. download hte pydev zip file, and extract to the dropins folder, still not working (could not find it in preference after restart eclipse)

I am very frustrated on this, could anyone help on this ? Thanks

My enviroment:

- OS: Mac 10.8
- Eclipse: 3.7
- Pydev: 3.0
- Country: China

Comment: Not much to go on!  Which errors?  What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: @cdarke, I have update it in my question

Comment: but you did not update with answers to my questions!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is just getting the LiClipse standalone: http://brainwy.github.io/liclipse/ (which has PyDev and some other things -- such as a bundled JRE, egit, color theme, etc -- pre-configured).

Now, if you don't want to go that way, I think that since PyDev 3.0 was released, the most common issue is not having Java 7 installed (as from 3.0 onwards PyDev requires it and Eclipse is not good at telling you that this is a problem and just hides PyDev if you have an older VM).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but I manually installed it and everything was solved.

I did this:

- downloaded zip files containing pydev from [HERE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/)
- unzipped features and plugins on respective directories on my eclipse installation directory
- finally from eclipse : new Pydev project. right click on directory project -> properties -> on PYTHONPATH you should be able to configure your interpreter.

Comment: what does it meand not working?!can't see pydev? errors? can't see pydev perspective? what?

Comment: could not find it in preference

Comment: in the zip file there are features and plugins folder, you need to copy these to the eclipse folder, then restart Eclipse

Comment: @zjffdu yes. I have tried this as well but it doesn't work, in installed softwares its showing pydev as installed but its not available in the preferences neither in new project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I opened Eclipse as admin and it worked... don't know if it helps

Answer (score -1):

Okay, here is the simple solution for you.

Open Eclipse and go to help>>Install new software and click on Add>> [pyDev](http://pydev.org/updates). and then update from Eclipse.